# Input doesnt get focus on it when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

The input element doesnt seem to get focused on click of a button on the first go, But later on it is working. Not sure why it is not being focused on the first go, can some one help

Sandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/enable-the-input-text-field-on-clicking-of-a-button-forked-ybgtxb?file=/src/index.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import * as data from "./messages.json";

const App = () => {
  return <Test {...{ alreadySetVal1: true, alreadySetVal2: true }} />;
};

const Test = ({ alreadySetVal1, alreadySetVal2 }) => {
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState(alreadySetVal1 ? "Already Set" : "");
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState(alreadySetVal2 ? "Already Set" : "");
  const [config, setConfig] = useState({
    config1: !!input1,
    config2: !!input2
  });
  const ref1 = useRef(null);
  const ref2 = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          disabled={config.config1}
          value={input1}
          ref={ref1}
          type={config.config1 ? "text" : "password"}
          onChange={(e) => setInput1(e.target.value)}
        />
        <span
          onClick={() => {
            setInput1("");
            setConfig({ ...config, config1: false });
            ref1.current.focus();
          }}
        >
          Enable Input 1
        </span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          disabled={config.config2}
          value={input2}
          ref={ref2}
          type={config.config2 ? "text" : "password"}
          onChange={(e) => setInput2(e.target.value)}
        />
        <span
          onClick={() => {
            setInput2("");
            setConfig({ ...config, config2: false });
            ref2.current.focus();
          }}
        >
          Enable Input 2
        </span>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

render(<App messages={data.messages} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Setting the focus on the first click via React doesn't work because the `input` element is currently still disabled.

## Solution

Convert the `span` elements to `label` elements and link them to their respective `input` element by `id` attribute. When the label for inputs are clicked the inputs receive the focus.

Example:

```
<div>
  <input
    id="input1" // <-- add id attribute
    disabled={config.config1}
    value={input1}
    type={config.config1 ? "text" : "password"}
    onChange={(e) => setInput1(e.target.value)}
  />
  <label
    htmlFor="input1" // <-- label for specific input
    onClick={() => {
      setInput1("");
      setConfig({ ...config, config1: false });
    }}
  >
    Enable Input 1
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <input
    id="input2"
    disabled={config.config2}
    value={input2}
    type={config.config2 ? "text" : "password"}
    onChange={(e) => setInput2(e.target.value)}
  />
  <label
    htmlFor="input2"
    onClick={() => {
      setInput2("");
      setConfig({ ...config, config2: false });
    }}
  >
    Enable Input 2
  </label>
</div>
```

[image: Edit input-doesnt-get-focus-on-it-when-button-is-clicked]

## Solution #2

This is a bit hackish IMO, but if you want to use the React ref to programatically set the focus then you can use a `setTimeout` with a callback to set the focus. Using the the `setTimeout` will place the callback at the end of the event queue and be processed *after* the React state update has been processed and the component rerendered, thus making the input focusable.

Example:

```
<div>
  <input
    disabled={config.config1}
    value={input1}
    ref={ref1}
    type={config.config1 ? "text" : "password"}
    onChange={(e) => setInput1(e.target.value)}
  />
  <span
    onClick={() => {
      setInput1("");
      setConfig({ ...config, config1: false });
      setTimeout(() => {
        ref1.current.focus();
      });
    }}
  >
    Enable Input 1
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <input
    disabled={config.config2}
    value={input2}
    ref={ref2}
    type={config.config2 ? "text" : "password"}
    onChange={(e) => setInput2(e.target.value)}
  />
  <span
    onClick={() => {
      setInput2("");
      setConfig({ ...config, config2: false });
      setTimeout(() => {
        ref2.current.focus();
      })
    }}
  >
    Enable Input 2
  </span>
</div>
```

[image: Edit input-doesnt-get-focus-on-it-when-button-is-clicked (forked)]

Comment: any idea why it is not being focused on the first go? Also any workaround without changing it to label

Comment: @li97 Not working the first time, not sure... but you really should be using a `label` element to label inputs as it's the correct semantic HTML element to do what you want and meets accessibility requirements for the web.

Comment: In my current application, there is already a label to the left of input. I havent added that in the sandbox, so each row has a label, input and a edit button/link

Comment: @li97 Ah, took another look and think the issue is that the input is still disabled at the moment the `span`'s `onClick` is processing. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import * as data from "./messages.json";

const App = () => {
  return <Test {...{ alreadySetVal1: true, alreadySetVal2: true }} />;
};

const Test = ({ alreadySetVal1, alreadySetVal2 }) => {
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState(alreadySetVal1 ? "Already Set" : "");
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState(alreadySetVal2 ? "Already Set" : "");
  const [config, setConfig] = useState({
    config1: !!input1,
    config2: !!input2
  });
  const ref1 = useRef(null);
  const ref2 = useRef(null);
 

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          disabled={config.config1}
          value={input1}
          ref={ref1}
          type={config.config1 ? "text" : "password"}
          onChange={(e) => setInput1(e.target.value)}
        />
        <span
          onClick={async () => {
            setInput1("");
              await Promise.all([
                setConfig({ ...config, config1: false }),
              ]);
              ref1.current.focus()
          }}
        >
          Enable Input 1
        </span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          disabled={config.config2}
          value={input2}
          ref={ref2}
          type={config.config2 ? "text" : "password"}
          onChange={(e) => setInput2(e.target.value)}
        />
        <span
          onClick={async() => {
            setInput2("");
            await Promise.all([
              setConfig({ ...config, config2: false }),
            ]);
              ref2.current.focus();
          }}
        >
          Enable Input 2
        </span>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

render(<App messages={data.messages} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Problem:** Here problem is you call `setConfig({ ...config, config1: false }),` AND `ref1.current.focus();` in a single render so `ref1.current.focus();` this focus can't understand is previous state changes.

**Solution:** So, solution is you need a complete `setConfig({ ...config, config1: false }),` this call first then call `ref1.current.focus();` .
Here possible solution is either you use `setTimeout` or `promise.all`.
Here I use promise.all because `promise.all` is comparatively good approach than using `setTimeout`

You can check here what promis.all do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all